# ADD or modify column in one call (upsert) - avoid DROP calls

Tags: postgresql

I have this call:

```
ALTER TABLE mbk_user ADD login_attempts int;
```

I want to update it to:

```
ALTER TABLE mbk_user ADD login_attempts int NOT NULL;
```

is there a way to do "ADD or MODIFY" in one sql statement (an upsert), or do I need to drop the column first and then ADD it again? I want to avoid drop statements ideally.

Comment: Upsert is a term usually used for something  different: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Comment: yeah but here I want to add or modify in one call

Comment: There is no DDL operation for that AFAIK. It is probably easiest to check INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS from your host language and do one operation or the other depending on the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in one call. (Why do you need to?) You **can** do this in a script without knowing or checking whether the column already exists or is currently NOT NULL.

You can run these two statements against the table in this order, whether or not the column exists and whether or not it is NOT NULL. The result will be that the column will exist and be NOT NULL.

```
ALTER TABLE mbk_user ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS login_attempts int NOT NULL ;
ALTER TABLE mbk_user ALTER COLUMN login_attempts SET NOT NULL ;
```

If the column doesn't already exist, it gets added in the first statement, and then gets set to NOT NULL in the second statement, which it already was so nothing else happens.

If the column does already exist, the first statement tries to add it, but does nothing because the column already exists (you might get a harmless warning), then sets it to NOT NULL in the second statement. If it was already NOT NULL, nothing will happen.

Comment: yeah that's too bad to be honest :( but thanks for explanation

Comment: don't *need* it, just want to do DRY and I fear with repetition the lines will get out of sync and cause errors when doing db migrations etc

Comment: btw I assume you could get rid of the `int NOT NULL;` from the first line if you wanted to?

Comment: You could run those two lines repeatedly, and as long as they always run in that order (ALTER TABLE ... ADD ..., then ALTER TABLE ... ALTER ...), you'll be fine. These lines are a "matched set" with each other, in the sense that they are both required to do what you want. They are no more likely to get "out of sync" than one longer command is, at least under circumstances that I can imagine. Also, you can't get rid of the "int", but you could get rid of NOT NULL. I don't advise it. It's better to make the column correctly to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to make the column NOT NULL. This can be done with the `ALTER <column_name>` [sub-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

```
ALTER TABLE mbk_user ALTER login_attempts SET NOT NULL;
```

Obviously this only works if there are no NULL values in that column.

Comment: yeah what I am looking for is an "upsert" call, if you are familiar. but I guess I can use ADD + ALTER, just more verbose.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. If the column isn't yet in the table, your second statement works. If the column is already part of the table you can use the statement from my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - maybe you could issue an `UPDATE mbk_user SET login_attempts = 0 WHERE login_attempts IS NULL` before issuing your `ALTER TABLE...` command

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am trying to do this automatically with some scripts, yes everything is easier in a one-off with human supervision